# Excel Diagramm Seriesnames in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, diagramming

I'm programming a Makro for a Excel xy-Diagramm
The diagramm is nearly correct, but i have dublicate DataSeriesNames;
I already tried to go through all Series and Compare the Names.
There were no Errors, but it didn't work.

Code was like that:

```
For a=1 to Count
  If ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Count).Name = Range("A2").Value Then
    Name = true
  End If
  a = a + 1
Next

If Name = false Then
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
End If
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Count).Name = "='Tasks'!$D$" & i
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Count).XValues = "='Tasks'!$B$" & i
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Count).Values = "='Tasks'!$C$" & i
```

Mfg Robin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong here.

First of all, you're always looking at the same series! I think you want to replace `Count` with `a` in your `If` statement.

```
If ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(a).Name
```

Secondly, once that is corrected, even if your `Name` variable gets set to `True` at some point, it may get reset to `False` later as the `For...Next` loop continues iterating through the remainder of the series collection. To prevent this, add an `Exit For` like this:

```
For a = 1 To Count
  If ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(a).Name = Range("A2").Value Then
    Name = True
    Exit For
  End If
  a = a + 1
Next
```

Also, I suspect you haven't declaring `Name` as a Boolean variable, so by default it's a Variant so its value isn't `False` to start with! You should declare the variable at the top of your procedure with `Dim Name as Boolean`, and then if you want `Name` to be `False` by default, you should really say so explicitly: Put `Name = False` before the loop. Moreover, `Name` is a terrible name for a variable... and so is `Count` Argh! I think your code should look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MySub()
    Dim a As Long
    Dim NameExists As Boolean
    Dim SeriesCount As Long

    SeriesCount = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count

    NameExists = False
    For a = 1 To SeriesCount 
      If ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(a).Name = Range("A2").Value Then
          NameExists = True
          Exit For
      End If
      a = a + 1
    Next

    If NameExists = False Then
    ' Rest of your code goes here...

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I corrected this things. it still doesn't work. the variable Name turns true always.. even if the name doesn't exist. i don't know why.

Comment: the thing with boolean and = false i had. My mistake was, that i didn't use ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count.. now it works. thx very much=)